# Is there a way to show a string instead if numeric column has specific value?

Tags: postgresql

I have a float column called "weight". It's default is -1, showing the object wasn't weighted. Is it possible to show string "unweighted" instead of any negative number in the field?

As it is internally stored:

```
 ________________________
| object_id  |  weight   |
|____________|___________|
|     1      |   12.4    |
|     2      |    7.5    |
|     3      |   -1      |
|____________|___________|
```

And now how the table should appear to the user:

```
 ________________________
| object_id  |  weight   |
|____________|___________|
|     1      |   12.4    |
|     2      |    7.5    |
|     3      |unweighted |
|____________|___________|
```

The table with the combined float/text column can be a view; still, I have no idea how to do it. Is it possible, or is doing the translation (negative number -> 'unweighted') on client side my only option?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you want to mix numeric and string values in the same column you need to convert the numbers to strings as well.

```
select object_id,
       case 
         when weight < 0 then 'unweighted'
         else weight::text
       end as weight
from the_table;
```

As that column is no longer a number, you can not sort or compare it properly any more. If you want to put that into a view, I suggest you create an additional column for this purpose:

```
select object_id,
       weight,
       case 
         when weight < 0 then 'unweighted'
         else weight::text
       end as display_weight
from the_table;
```

However it would be cleaner if you don't use "magic numbers" to mark the absence of data. Precisely for this reason the `NULL` value was created in SQL (although using `NULL` won't solve the problem of mixing numeric and string values in the same column).